# How to make a request with a conversion specifier in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, conversion-specifier

I'm trying to send a query that is URL-encoded as follows. However, an error occurs because % and & in the query are recognized as conversion specifiers. How do I solve it?

```
import requests

requests.get("8.8.8.8/abc.php?strrh=%3d%81%26%ad%f94%5c%f0%3c%cej%c00%a4%e5x%07%06%92%da&id=%f9&num=1124")
```

Comment: What error, *exactly*, do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [urllib.parse.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to properly form the query string in the URL.